# Are questions regarding print production suited for GDSE?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am wondering whether questions regarding certain aspects of the actual physical production of a graphic design product are suited to be asked on GDSE.

By that I not merely mean print production - which I would consider to be inherently part of the design process of a print product rather than considering the graphic designer's job to end when the file is sent  and the computer turned off - but also other material production aspects such as book binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES. If the graphic design is intended for print, then details of print production are entirely relevant. To generalize, yes, ditto for any other kind of production.

I am both a graphic designer and a printer; I cannot tell you how often we receive "print-ready" artwork from 3rd-party graphic designers who have no concept of print production, esp. bindery.

To clarify: It is the responsibility of the designer, and a mandatory part of any design, to conform with specifications and conditions that the design will be used in or subject to.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see why they would be off-topic and I would welcome questions like these! Not that I could answer, but curious to learn!

Comment: More questions on these topics would potentially give me more of a foothold to be active on gd.se.